# How can I change a cloned repo to a read/write one

Tags: git, github, ssh, bitbucket, ssh-keys

I have a repository on bitbucket.

I added SSH keys from my machine to the *SSH Key* section

I then cloned my repo to my machine and changed a readme.txt file

I performed the following

```
 git status
 git add .
 git commit -m “updated readme”
 git push
```

I get access denied

Comment: Did you add the key to your account, or to the repo?

Comment: I generated the ssh key on the machine then copied the value to the repo

Comment: You need to remove it from the repo and put it on your account.

Comment: It’s my own repo

Comment: That doesn't matter - if the key is in your account, then that's how you authenticate as yourself. If the key's in the repo, then that's how you'd authenticate as a CI/CD system.

Answer (score 0):

> I generated the ssh key on the machine then copied the value to the repo

Make sure to:

- copy the public key content to your account SSH setting
- have the private key in your `HOME/.ssh` folder

Comment: @softwareisfun Is this your own repo? or are you declared as a collavorator on that repo? Is it a private or public repo?

Comment: @softwareisfun What service are you using? GitHub? Bitbucket? GitLab? AWS CodeComitt? Knowing what's the beast helps a lot when we answer as different systems support different types of configuration and setup. I.E, Butcucket has repo level authentication whereas GitHub has only user and organisation member level authentication and public forking and private.